# Flutter: APK Requires Promiment disclosure/APK Requires valid privacy

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I'm trying to publish a new version of my app on the Google Play console. Before it was fine but now I'm having difficult because it keeps rejected by Google. I did some research on different sites regarding on the issue for a fix but I could not find anything related to Flutter. Based on the eligibility issue it mention "Stripe SDK" but on my app I don't have or I didn't use any Stripe SDK package etc. I did do project wide search on my project source but I could not find any Stripe keywords. I only have in_app_purchase package (I'm not sure if there is something to do with it) I also added the privacy policy on the Play Developer Console and on the App itself but it still rejected. Has someone encountered this issue and how to fix it?

[Screenshot from Google Play Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCkOc.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Analyze your apk to see if the manifest contains the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

and also make sure none of your dependencies use the said permission or StripeSDK.
for details how to analyze apk visit:
[docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer)